# Meaning of declaration of function

Tags: c, function, definition

I've been reading the `stdio.h` file and I'm confused.

For example, there is this line:

```
_CRTIMP FILE* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW fopen (const char*, const char*);
```

I know `FILE*` means returning type and I found that `_CRTIMP` is constant, defined as

```
# ifndef _CRTIMP
#  define _CRTIMP  __declspec(dllimport)
# endif
```

I don't understand it, what is it there for? And what are rest of strings (`__cdecl`, `__MINGW_NOTHROW`) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`__declspec(dllimport)` specifies that the function is to be imported from a separate dll; I suppose that, depending on the CRT static/dynamic linking settings, it's defined in different ways.

`__cdecl` is the calling convention used for the function; the calling convention tells to the compiler how the function expects to be called (in which order parameters are pushed on the stack, if any register is used for parameters, where the return value is stored, who is responsible for stack cleanup, ...); in general you shouldn't worry about it as long as you're not writing libraries.

`__MINGW_NOTHROW` is `#define`d to expand to `__attribute__ ((__nothrow__))`, which is a MinGW-specific extension that tells to the compiler that the function will not throw exceptions; this lets the compiler perform some optimizations.

Note that all these are not standard C attributes, but compiler/platform specific stuff. Again, in general you shouldn't worry about them, they are required to make the CRT work fine, but as long as you're not building libraries you can get away without knowing anything about them. `:)`

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at `_mingw.h` and the [gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/): In case of gcc - or any other compiler supporting `__GNUC__` - the following definitions apply:

```
#define __cdecl  __attribute__ ((__cdecl__))
#define __MINGW_NOTHROW __attribute__ ((__nothrow__))
```

The former tells the compiler to use the [cdecl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) x86 calling convention ([see gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-functions-that-do-pop-the-argument-stack-on-the-386-2405)), the latter that the function is guaranteed not to throw C++ exceptions ([see gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bnothrow_007d-function-attribute-2465)).

`__declspec(dllimport)` is necessary to make dynamic linking work ([see gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007b_005f_005fdeclspec_0028dllimport_0029_007d-2414)).

Answer (score 1):

`__declspec(dllimport)` tells the compiler that this function needs to be imported from a DLL, it's a Windows-specific extension. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx) for details.

Likewise, `__cdecl` is an attribute that specifies that the function uses a particular calling convention (namely, the one used by C). See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

I would guess that the __MINGW_NOTHROW macro is a synonym for the GCC `nothrow` attribute, which informs the compiler that the function in question cannot throw exceptions. See the [documentation](http://www.ohse.de/uwe/articles/gcc-attributes.html#func-nothrow) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Theses are declarations specific to the environment or the compiler you're using.

- The `__declspec(dllimport)` indicates, on windows, that this function is in a dll and should be placed in the import table of the executable PE file generated.
- The `__cdecl` indicate a standard C calling convention and will modify the way the compiler transform the function to conform to this calling convention.
- `__MINGW_NOTHROW` is specific to your compiler and might de-activate support for exception.

In all case, there must be an explanation in the documentation of your compiler.